# Bandwidth of low pass filter

Tags: filter, bandwidth

Say I have some low pass filter of the form:

$$G(s) = \frac{a}{s+b}$$

How do I find the bandwidth? I know for example that with bandpass filters it's the difference between +-3dB of the cutoff frequency but I'm not sure how that would work for this example.

Comment: I converted your image to a formula using Mathjax, so it can be read by screen readers, etc. For more information see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/7195

Comment: @JYelton thanks! I was having trouble doing that for somereason...although it's worked for me before.

Comment: Sometimes I've noticed a delay when loading Mathjax scripts. Perhaps it was just being slow. :)

Comment: That may have been it. My connection is rather slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case $$G(s) = \frac{a}{s+b} = \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)\left( \frac {1}{1+\frac {s}{b}}\right)$$

The output will be -3dB compared to the passband when \$s = jb\$  (equivalent to \$\frac{b}{2\pi}\$ Hz) so the bandwidth is \$b\$ radians/second and the passband gain is (a/b).

Answer (score 0):

Bandwidth is just a matter of definition, of how we label what's around us.

A low pass filter is a box that let all the frequencies up to the cutoff pass *almost* untouched, so the width of the bunch of frequencies that can pass is from 0 to \$f_C\$, and we call this bandwidth.

A 100Hz cut off low pass filter has a band of 100Hz. Just think of it as a bandpass with the lowest frequency being zero...

Comment: Hmmm. So you don't have to do anything with +-3dB...that's easy then I guess :)

Comment: Wait, of course: the cut off frequency is defined as the frequency where the amplitude is -3dB with respect to center band.